# Bundler: ensure production gems installed system-wide?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a ruby program in my git repo, used by a team. It's executed directly out of the git repo. I don't want all the team members to have to deal with gems, so I want the production-level gems to be installed system-wide (on shared disk). Bundler will use the git-controlled Gemfile.lock to decide which gems to pick up.

For development, I often install gems using --user-install.

Problem: I might accidentally push changes that use gems which are only user-installed, which will break other team members when they pull and try to run.

How can I ensure that all non-development gems are installed system-wide?

Is there a bundle command I can run that will detect this and throw an error? Or can I somehow get my cucumber tests to run using only system gems?

Comment: I am not yet sure that I understand your team members setup. Who uses which computer with which shared or not shared repo? Somehow to me the description "smells" a bit, as if there was a better way to do this (thought about a web-application?) Regarding your question, I think that @Ginty s answer is what you need.

Comment: @Felix, each team member has their own clone of the repo, with the ruby program as part of it. But I don't want each team member to have to run bundler every time I add a new third-party gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get Bundler to use System gems, though I think there should be: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1964

The most straightforward solution for you would be to package the gems into your Git repo: http://bundler.io/v1.12/bundle_package.html.
This is really how the bundler team recommend that it should be run in a case where you want a user to be able to run your app without having to install gems locally.

A second option would be for you to use the --path option to bundle install and point that to a shared location visible to all your users. This option is remembered, so check .bundle into your Git repo and then your users would use the same configuration and reference the same location when they run bundle. Since all of the gems would already be installed there by you, they would have no problems.

Comment: Checking in .bundle/config sounds like a recipe for disaster. As I develop in my own repo and install gems in my home directory I might inadvertently submit my own local .bundle/config.

Comment: I ended up running `bundle package` and submitting the vendor/cache directory with the gems in it. Then each user runs `bundle install --deployment --without development --local --standalone` to unpack those gems for their local repo. Decided not to rely on system gems at all since I couldn't find a robust way to do it.